# FOSUser : templates are not showing CSS after deployment SF4

Tags: css, symfony4, fosuserbundle

My CSS is not displayed on my FOSUser template after deployment. In local, everything's fine.
I followed the documention of FOSUser and I don't understand what's going on.

'Could you help me please ?'

base.html.twig

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr-FR">
<head>

    {% block stylesheets %}
        ...
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/index.css">
    {% endblock %}
</head>

<body>


    {% block content %}

    {% endblock %}

...
```

'layout.html.twig'

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}


{% block content %}
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                {% block fos_user_content %}{% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

example of my login template with FOSUser :

```
{% extends "FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block stylesheets %} {% endblock %}

{% block fos_user_content %}

.....

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: remove this line `{% block stylesheets %} {% endblock %}` from login template

Comment: Hello Ravai,

Thanks for your reply. I tried to follow your advice but.. it doesn't work

Comment: I think your css path was incorrect could you please correct via this assert or webpack

Comment: Hello Ravi, I installed Webpack ENCORE but nothing to do. I really do not understand. Really weird. It works in local but not after deployment.